# Sharing registry and user store between WSO2 ESB and IDS

Tags: wso2, datasource, wso2-identity-server, wso2-esb

We are using WSO2 products ESB and IS in our product.  We have configured MySql datasource for user stores and registry in Identity Server.  We also have tenant specific user stores configured in Identity Server.

We would like to configure ESB to use the same user stores that are of Identity Server.

We have tried configuring the datasources and user-mgt.xml with the same user stores.  When ESB is being launched we're getting some exceptions.

Kindly advise the following:
If we want to share registry and user stores, can we just add the datasources in master-datasources.xml and refer them in respective xml in ESB?  Or, anything different?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. You can just share same user-mgt.xml and master-datasources.xml file with both ESB and IS. If you want to point to the same user store, user management database and same registry. (if registry.xml file has not been changed). But there can be issues, if ESB and IS are not release with same carbon platform. Because there can be slightly different between the user kernel implementation of two different carbon versions.  Could you let us know the ESB and IS version  that you are using? Also errors that you see in ESB startup?

Comment: Thanks for your response, we're using ESB 4.7.0 and IS 4.1.0.  I shall share the errors too